# How to copy records (distinct in one column but keep data in other fields) to a new table and assign new id in MySQL

Tags: mysql

For example, I have one table here:

```
id, firstname, lastname, age, country
 1, john     , doe     , 40 , usa
 2, mary     , kay     , 30 , uk
 3, john     , doe     , 41 , usa
 4, peter    , pan     , 50 , australia
```

I would like to copy the rows with distinct(firstname) also with latest id to a new table, but keep the data in other field, also reassign the id, like:

```
id, firstname, lastname, age, country
 1, mary     , kay     , 30 , uk
 2, john     , doe     , 41 , usa
 3, peter    , pan     , 50 , australia
```

Please advise how can I do it with MySQL query, thanks!

Comment: Create a new table with id column auto_increment,insert ..select where id is max id for name.

Answer (score 0):

First find the rows with max id for same firstname in subquery and then use user variables to reassign them the id starts with 1.

Try this if you just want to select it:

```
select
    @rn := @rn + 1 id,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    age,
    country
from (
    select a.*
    from t a
    left join t b
    on a.firstname = b.firstname and a.id < b.id
    where b.firstname is null
) t cross join (select @rn := 0) x order by id;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/JDFSF75355)

You can easily create an insert from this:

```
insert into some_table(id,firstname,lastname,age,country)
select
    @rn := @rn + 1 id,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    age,
    country
from (
    select a.*
    from t a
    left join t b
    on a.firstname = b.firstname and a.id < b.id
    where b.firstname is null
) t cross join (select @rn := 0) x order by id;
```

If you want to use autoincrement on id in the new table, then simply use:

```
insert into some_table(firstname,lastname,age,country)
select
    a.firstname,
    a.lastname,
    a.age,
    a.country
from t a
left join t b
on a.firstname = b.firstname and a.id < b.id
where b.firstname is null
order by a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to insert with a select [MySQL INSERT-SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO new_table ( firstname, lastname, age, country ) 
    SELECT firstname, lastname, age, country 
    FROM old_table 
    GROUP BY old_table.firstname 
    ORDER BY old_table.id DESC
```

Note: You need `auto increment` field for `new_table(id)`for this approach

Comment: Why do you think so?